# Pytorch read multiple files at the same time in forward method

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, preprocessor

I am creating a PyTorch model and I have added paths in the forward method but the training time is increased a lot. Is there a way, I can parallelize the reading and preprocess of paths.

```
paths = [['./a.wav', './b.wav'], ['./c.wav', 'd.wav']]

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, preprocess_fn):
        self.linear = nn.linear(100, 2)
        self.relu = nn.Relu()
        self.preprocess = preprocess_fn

    def forward(self, path_1, path_2):
        x = self.preprocess(path_1)
        y = self.preprocess(path_2)
        x = torch.cat([x, y]).view(-1, 100)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return self.relu(x)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you not using a Dataset and DataLoader?

Comment: I have used, Tried parallelism too but it is not working. [I have posted another question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900959/pytorch-dataset-read-in-multiple-audio-files-in-parallel)