# PyTorch Dataset: Read multiple audio files in parallel error Can't get attribute 'AudioDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I am trying to create a PyTorch `Dataset` for reading two audio files as features. The code is designed to take two audio paths and preprocess it and return spectrograms, features, etc. and it is taking a lot of time. While creating a dataset it takes a lot of time around 15 minutes for 900 files although the dataset is small I have good memory available. Is there a way, I can improve its performance using parallelism or any other method?

```
class AudioDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, paths_list, targets, preprocess=preprocess_fn):

        self.preprocess = preprocess
        self.features = []
        self.labels = []
        self.paths_list = paths_list
        
        self.targets = targets
        self._init_dataset()
        
    
    def _init_dataset(self):
        
#         paths_list, targets
        try:
            for p, target in tqdm(zip(self.paths_list, self.targets)):
                audio_1 = self.preprocess(p[0])
                audio_2 = self.preprocess(p[1])
                self.features.append([audio_1, audio_2])
                self.labels.append(target)
        
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Error occured at {e}")

            
#         self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.features[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return sample, label
```

Tried using DataLoader with setting number of workers=10, but it throws an error

```
[00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/cm/local/apps/python37/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "/cm/local/apps/python37/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'AudioDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

The code works without multiple workers.
Is there a way I can get it sorted?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To increase the speed of loading you should consider saving the features into .pt files and design a different dataset and loader for reading the features from the .pt files. It's called transfer learning. You can google it. For the error i think i need more information on the code and the stacktrace.